# Sub square matrix

Tags: matrices

Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}11&12&13&14\\21&22&23&24\\31&32&33&34\\41&42&43&44\end{bmatrix}$$

Consider the following two matrices

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}22&23&24\\32&33&34\\42&43&44\end{bmatrix}$$

$$C = \begin{bmatrix}21&23\\41&43\end{bmatrix}$$

$B$ is a square sub-matrix $(3$X$3)$ of $A$.

**Is $C$ also considered as a square sub-matrix $(2$X$2)$ of $A$?**

Comment: There is no such thing as "a matrix of $A$". However, both $B$ and $C$ are **submatrices** of $A$.

Comment: Sorry! its **sub-matrix**.